# Java 8 - Looping Map inside List using stream

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I have one list and map, where i need to iterate list first and inside that loop i need to access map to form String message. I have written the same in Java 7 and it works fine. Can someone help in converting this in Java 8 streaming.

```
        final Map<String, String> destTabMap = ... 
        final List<String> destTabs = mappingList.get(destTabName);

        for (int j=0; j < destTabs.size(); j++) {
            String destName = destTabs.get(j);

            final String fieldValue = destTabMap.get(destName);

            if(fieldValue==null)
                continue;


           message.append(destName+"  ");
           message.append(":");
           message.append("  "+fieldValue);
           message.append("\n");
           System.out.println(destName+"  : "+fieldValue);
        }
```

Comment: where is `mappingList` definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may do it like so,

```
String resultStr = destTabs.stream()
    .filter(s -> destTabMap.get(s) != null)
    .map(s -> s + "  :  " + destTabMap.get(s))
    .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
```

Comment: Using [`getOrDefault`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault(java.lang.Object,V)) could make the mapping cleaner.

Comment: Consider filtering out absent keys with `.filter(destTabMap::containsKey)`